# Installing centos server in a virtual machine

Tags: centos, virtualbox, system-installation

I want to learn CentOs so that I can manage my own web server. I did so by buying a dedicated and setting up CentOs. It's good, but the latency (around 300ms with Putty) is killing me when typing.

So I have decided to setup CentOS on my local machine. I have Windows XP and Virtual Box installed.

Simply, I want to install CentOs (the Server, not the Desktop GUI) either on the Virtual Box or as a separate OS (neck to neck with Windows XP) whichever is best and easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing CentOS into VirtualBox is the way to go. When you start to dual boot, things can get a little tricky. If you want to learn, a Virtual Guest is a great way to break something and keep moving since you can easily restore from snapshot or reinstall.

If all you want is command line with no GUI, one of the options during install asks what kind of you system you want. If you choose `Basic Server`, it will give you just that; a barebones server with no frills. After installation is complete, you will then need to install the packages you want or need. This is a great way to learn how to install packages and find out what's available.

This person has been kind enough to take [screenshots](http://isystemadmin.com/step-by-step-installation-guide-of-centos-6-2) of every step of the CentOS 6.2 installation.

Have fun and make new posts when you need help.

Comment: Good. Set it up! Any step by step guide for CentOs (just the command line)